# Two UICollection Views in one UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to have two different collectionViews, the personalCollectionView and the collabCollectionView, inside one tableView cell. However, when I trying using the collectionView dataSource methods to have a different cell count for each collectionView, the personalCollectionView always ends up having the same cell count as the collabCollectionView. This is my code below :

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    if collectionView == personalCollectionView {

        return 1
    }

    else {

        return 0
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if collectionView == personalCollectionView {

        return personalCollectionContent.count
    }

    else {

        return 0
    }

}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? If you have any questions/need any more info, please let me know!!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right, but I don't think the equality operator (`==`) works here. Try using the identity operator (`===`) to check the collection view.

Comment: I've used the equality operator to compare tableView's before and it's worked. I still tried using the identity operator though and that didn't work either :/